# Google Cloud Run masks Bearer token in Authorization header

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

The Google documentation for Cloud Run states that you can "pull the token out of the Authorization header" ([docs here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/end-users#getting_user_profile_information)) in order to validate it and obtain further information about the requesting user.

However, when reading the `Authorization` header while processing the request, it appears that parts of the token have been redacted after passing through Google's auth frontend. E.g

```
Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImY2ZjgwZjM3ZjIxYzIz.SIGNATURE_REMOVED_BY_GOOGLE
```

Is this a bug in Cloud Run or do we need to do something different to obtain the full Bearer token?

Answer (score 7):

Here are the details for the Authorization Header and SIGNATURE_REMOVED_BY_GOOGLE as seen inside Cloud Run:

1. If `allUsers` is enabled, the JWS signature comes thru and is not replaced.
2. If `allUsers` is not enabled AND the OIDC token is from a Google Account (gmail) then the signature is replaced.
3. If `allUsers` is not enabled AND the OIDC token is from a service account, then the signature is not replaced.

**[Update 3/8/2021]**

The reason that Google redacts the signature for Identity Tokens is to prevent Identity Token reuse. A valid Identity Token would allow the service to impersonate the user/account with another service which is a security risk.

Comment: In my case, the signature is replaced for the service account token as well

Comment: @Mihir - I just updated my answer to explain why Google redacts the signtaure.

Answer (score 3):

When I check the user identity, I only take the 2nd part of the token. Here a snippet of my Python code for doing this. I rely on Google for performing security/validation stuff, and thus, don't care about the signature.

```
    # get the JWT token after the Bearer prefix
    authorization = request.headers['Authorization'][7:] 
    # split the token and take only the 2nd part 
    b64_profile = authorization.split('.')[1] 
    # decode correctly the B64 token part
    profile = base64.b64decode(b64_profile + '=' * (-len(b64_profile) % 4)) 
    # load the JSON and enjoy!
    print(json.loads(profile)['email'])
```

*Note: email is sometime empty, in case of allUsers authorization*