# I can't call my private HTTP Cloud Function (401) bearer instead of Bearer & SIGNATURE_REMOVED_BY_GOOGLE

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-oauth

1. I have created a service account `account-name@project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com`.
2. I added the following roles to it: Cloud Functions Invoker & Logs Writer.
3. I have implemented the following cloud function:

```js
exports.getRandomInteger = functions
  .region(process.env.REGION)
  .runWith({ memory: "128MB", timeoutSeconds: 60 })
  .https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    return cors(req, res, async () => {
      try {
        validateHttpMethod(req, "GET");

        const authToken = getIdTokenFromRequest(req);

        await verifyIdToken(authToken);

        ...

        return res.status(200).send(randomInteger.toString());
      } catch (err) {
        if (err instanceof HttpError) {
          return res.status(err.statusCode).send(err.message);
        }

        // An internal server error has occurred
        functions.logger.error(err);

        return res.status(500).send(err);
      }
    });
  });
```

4. In the permission section of my cloud function, I removed `allUsers` from the Cloud Functions Invoker role, replacing it with the account created in step 1 `account-name@project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com`.
5. I log in correctly using `account-name@project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com` with a generated `key file` in the `gcloud CLI`.
6. I invoke the cloud function using cURL:

```
curl -i -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token)" \
https://project_location-project_id.cloudfunctions.net/getRandomInteger
```

7. I get the error UNAUTHORIZED:

```
HTTP/2 401 
vary: Origin
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
function-execution-id: hjkhjkfhkfjk
x-cloud-trace-context: xsaajk2h2jjsdk
date: Sat, 18 Mar 2023 02:40:54 GMT
server: Google Frontend
content-length: 12
```

8. This is my `getIdTokenFromRequest` helper:

```js
module.exports = (req) => {
  const authorizationHeader = req.headers.authorization;
  const sessionCookie = req.cookies?.__session;

  // Make sure there is a Bearer token in the Authorization header
  if (!authorizationHeader?.startsWith("Bearer ") && !sessionCookie) {
    throw AuthErrors.unauthorized();
  }

  if (authorizationHeader?.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
    return authorizationHeader.split("Bearer ")[1];
  }

  if (sessionCookie) {
    return sessionCookie;
  }

  throw AuthErrors.unauthorized();
};
```

9. This is my `verifyIdToken` helper:

```js
module.exports = async (token) => {
  try {
    const decodedIdToken = await admin.auth().verifyIdToken(token);

    return decodedIdToken;
  } catch (err) {
    throw AuthErrors.unauthorized();
  }
};
```

10. For some reason, when logging the bearer token in the cloud function, I see:

```
bearer X.Y.SIGNATURE_REMOVED_BY_GOOGLE
```

WHY? 'bearer' (lower case) instead of 'Bearer' . Signature replaced with SIGNATURE_REMOVED_BY_GOOGLE (??)

What did I do incorrectly? I have also configured a cloud workflow (using the same service account of the step 1) to call this function, following google documentation, but I get the same error UNAUTHORIZED:

```
main:
  params: []
  steps:
    - getRandomInteger:
        call: http.get
        args:
          url: https://project_location-project_id.cloudfunctions.net/getRandomInteger
          auth:
            type: OIDC
        result: randomInteger
    - sleep:
        call: sys.sleep
        args:
          seconds: randomInteger
    - returnOutput:
        return: OK
```

Comment: bearer and Bearer seems to be both correct, just check the testing tab of your cloud function (in the cloud console)... They use bearer and not Bearer. So, try with regex to accept both: `authorizationHeader.match(/^bearer\s(.+)$/i)` to split the token, and `authorizationHeader && (/^bearer\s/i).test(authorizationHeader)` to check if bearer token is present.

Comment: Google removes the signature to invalidate the Identity Token. Reason: If you call service A with an Identity Token, service A cannot then use the same Identity Token to call another service. This prevents a security vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

As [@JohnHanley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8016720) mentioned in their comment and [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73241584), this is done for security.

For the function to actually be invoked, the provided ID token must have passed validation. Additionally a Google Cloud ID token and a Firebase ID token are similar but functionally different which means you can't pass it to `admin.auth().verifyIdToken()` and get the proper result anyway.

Now that your function is executing, you can decode the JWT manually.

```js
function extractGCloudIdToken(req) {
  const authHeader = req.headers.authorization;
  if (!authHeader || !/^bearer /i.test(authHeader)) {
    throw AuthErrors.unauthorized();
  }

  let decodedIdToken = null;
  try {
    decodedIdToken = JSON.parse(
      Buffer
        .from(
          authHeader.split(" ")[1]?.split(".")[1],
          'base64'
        )
        .toString()
    );
  } catch () { /* suppressed */ }

  if (!decodedIdToken) {
    throw AuthErrors.unauthorized();
  }

  return decodedIdToken;
}
```

This is then used like so:

```js
exports.getRandomInteger = functions
  .region(process.env.REGION)
  .runWith({ memory: "128MB", timeoutSeconds: 60 })
  .https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    return cors(req, res, async () => {
      try {
        validateHttpMethod(req, "GET");
        const gcloudIdToken = extractGCloudIdToken(req);

        /* do stuff */

        return res.status(200).send(randomInteger.toString());
      } catch (err) {
        if (err instanceof HttpError) {
          return res.status(err.statusCode).send(err.message);
        }

        // An internal server error has occurred
        functions.logger.error(err);

        return res.status(500).send(err);
      }
    });
  });
```